# Updated translation keys in en_US not working

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I have added/updated the translation keys in en_US file. When I had added the translation it was working but once I have updated the keys. It stop working.

E.g in en_US file

I have added

In en_US.csv

"abc","test translation"

In phtml file

__("abc") displays "test translation"

The above works without any error

but when I have updated it to

In en_US.csv

"abc product- name","test updated translation"

In phtml file

__("abc") . ' ' . $_product->getName() displays "abc product- name"

it should display "test updated translation"

Is there anything more to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**CSV:** "abc %s","test updated translation %s"

**In Magento PHTML file:**

```
<?php echo __('abc %1', $_product->getName());  ?>
```

Hope it should work.

Comment: In en_US.csv

"abc product- name","test updated translation"

and it should be __("abc product- name")

Comment: I think I know the problem which you are referring, then product name should be inside the brackets

Comment: check my updated answer

Comment: Such a silly mistake by me, I got it working in this way
__('abc' . ' ' . $_product->getName()). but I will follow your way. I am actually new to php and magento. and your solution is a clean one. Thankyou

Comment: I have tried the solution
<?= __('abc %s', ($_product->getName())) ?> 
it displays abc %s

and originaly abc will be displayed by a variable, something like 
<?= __($_value . ' %s', ($_product->getName())) ?>

Comment: `<?php echo __('abc %s', ($_product->getName()));  ?>`

Comment: it displays abc %s

Comment: try updated code

Comment: This one worked :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74880/discussion-between-abhishek-panchal-and-jn-newbie).